Find n-element in sequence. How to speed up the programm (time) for n > 10^6?
I think I have right algorithm, but when the values increase to 106 and more, I exceed the MEMORY or TIMELIMIT allowed. At first I tried to push the elements to a vector, then I changed the method to reuse vars and more tests passed.
formula: Ai = (Ai-1 + 2 * Ai-2 + 3 * Ai-3) mod M, where M = 109 + 7.
1 <= n <= 1012 TIMELIMIT: 1 sec, MEMORY: 256mb
Code:
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;
using ull = unsigned long long;

ull func(ull n){
    ull a = 1;
    ull b = 1;
    ull c = 2;
    if (n < 2) return a;
    if (n == 3) return c;
    ull res = 0;
    for (ull i = 0; i < n - 3; i++){
        res = (3 * a + 2 * b + c) % (ull)(pow(10, 9) + 7);
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = res;
    }
    return c;
}

int main() {
    int x; 
    cin >> x;
    cout << func(x);
}

Now I have an algorithm which passes 3 initial tests (and then failed 63 test, where I think values > 10^6)
Test 1
Input: 6
Output: 34
Test 2
Input: 10
Output: 1096
Test 3
Input: 500
Output: 340736120
Do I need to change the algorithm or speed up by any methods?

As a general rule, whenever the challenge contains mod 100000007, there is a formula for this which doesn't involve doing the calculations. You have to do the Maths first.

Calculate 10^9 + 7 once before the loop (you can simply store 100000007 in a const variable) . And in general don't use pow for integer exponentiation.

There is an O(log n) algorithm for this. I don't know if I should just tell you what it is
(kind of spoils the challenge), but knowing that it exists may help you find it.

@wohlstad, That i can use instead of pow?

@lilof but when values increase to 10^6 and more, I have MEMORY or TIMELIMIT -- And you've come across one of the tricks these "competitive coding" websites use.  The trick is that the questions asked on those sites almost always has an easy-to-code, naive solution that never works if the data set is large.   Unless the question you are trying to answer is marked as "beginner", there is no way a simple one-line loop that doesn't do anything special is going to work.  The goal is to figure out the algorithm, data structure(s), or math, to get a solution to work for large sets of data.


Why did you tag this as biginteger?  2) (ull)(pow(10, 9) + 7 -- This is a constant.  There is no need to compute this value over and over again.  Maybe the compiler's optimizer sees this and moves this out of the loop, but you cannot rely on this.


https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62013/552

@lilof yes. You can add const unsigned long long t = 100000007; before the loop and then use t instead of pow(10, 9) + 7. Having said that, it is probably more significant to reduce the complexity of the algoeithm as other suggested. Also note that having using ull = unsigned long long; is considered bad practice.

@BoP, ok thanks, i will try;

Now i use it, no changes; const unsigned long long t = 1000000007;
res = ((3 * a + 2 * b) % t + (c % t)) % t;

n can be 1e12 which is far too big for your algorithm. No CPU runs at more than 1e10 GHz and you need to do that in 1 second. This is not possible with your algorithm. Thus, your assumption "I think I have right algorithm" is wrong. You need another algorithm. For that, please read the past comments more carefully, especially the ones of of user555045 and PresidentJamesK.Polk carefully (alternatively, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Matrix_form may help too).

Consider posting here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

@JérômeRichard, Did I understand correctly that in that example with the Fibonacci sequence, it can also work for this sequence? I just think maybe this task is beyond my strength.

Yes, probably. This was the point. You "just" need to find the coefficient matrix. I think it should be a 3x3 matrix since you have 3 terms. Once you have the coefficient, then writing the code squaring the matrix is pretty easy. To find the coefficient, you need to understand how it works precisely with Fibonacci. Note you can easily test the method with math-related tools (also even in Matlab or Python with Numpy). There are also C++ libraries for matrices (eg. Eigen). On the math side, I think you need to know what matrices are and how to use them to solve basic math problems.

Technically, this problem is more a math problem than programming one (or even one focusing on how to design efficient algorithms). If your goal is to learn programming, then it might not be the best exercice and I advise you you try another one. Be aware though that it is common to use advanced math to solve complex programming problems (eg. large graphs analysis, AI stuff, cryptography, finance/physics stuff, etc.).

Thank you for detailed answer and advice. I think, with the proper serious approach, this can be sorted out. I guess I'll come back to this task later then. This is my first question on stackoverflow, should I close the question?

Is this a problem on some online judge? If so, do you have a link?

It's problem from Regional stage ICPC, from codeforces, competition for me end 3     in 11 problems solved. I try to find the link.

Your current solution is O(n) which is much too slow when n can be as large as 1012.
We can find a matrix M such that we can transition from one state to the next by multiplying. M satisfies
[Ai, Ai-1, Ai-2]T = M * [Ai-1, Ai-2, Ai-3]T
Clearly, the last row of M is simply [0, 1, 0] to get Ai-2.
Similarly, the second row is [1, 0, 0].
The first row is [1, 2, 3], which directly comes from the recurrence relation.
Now, for n > 3, we can find the nth element of the sequence by (left) multiplying the initial conditions, [A3, A2, A1] = [2, 1, 1], with M a total of n-3 times, then reading off the answer from the first row. This is equivalent to multiplying by Mn-3. Matrix exponentiation can be performed in O(S3 log(N)) where S is the dimension of the matrix (in this case, the constant 3) and N is the exponent with binary exponentiation.
This leads to the following solution:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <span>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstddef>
constexpr int MOD = 1e9 + 7;
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
    std::size_t rows, cols;
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> values;

public:
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) : rows{rows}, cols{cols}, values(rows, std::vector<T>(cols)) {}
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> initVals) : rows{initVals.size()} {
        values.reserve(rows);
        for (auto& row : initVals) {
            values.emplace_back(row);
            if ((cols = row.size()) != values[0].size()) throw std::domain_error("Not a matrix: rows have unequal size");
        }
    }
    std::span<T> operator[](std::size_t r) {
        return values[r];
    }
    std::span<const T> operator[](std::size_t r) const {
        return values[r];
    }
    static Matrix identity(std::size_t size) {
        Matrix id(size, size);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) id.values[i][i] = 1;
        return id;
    }
    Matrix operator*(const Matrix& m) const {
        if (cols != m.rows) throw std::domain_error("Matrix dimensions do not match");
        Matrix res(rows, m.cols);
        for (std::size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
            for (std::size_t c = 0; c < m.cols; ++c)
                for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
                    res.values[r][c] += values[r][i] * m.values[i][c];
        return res;
    }
    Matrix operator%(T mod) const {
        auto res = *this;
        for (std::size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
            for (std::size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
                res.values[r][c] %= mod;
        return res;
    }
    Matrix modPow(std::size_t exp, T mod) const {
        if (rows != cols) throw std::domain_error("Matrix is not square");
        auto res = identity(rows), sq = *this;
        for (; exp; exp >>= 1) {
            if (exp & 1) res = res * sq % mod;
            sq = sq * sq % mod;
        }
        return res;
    }
};
const Matrix<unsigned long long> transition{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
                                 initialConditions{{2}, {1}, {1}};
unsigned long long nthValue(unsigned long long n){
    if (n < 3) return 1;
    return (transition.modPow(n - 3, MOD) * initialConditions % MOD)[0][0];
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long n; 
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << nthValue(n) << '\n';
}

